# Alter/edit data inserted into table

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I've created a login and register page where people can login or register if they are new, and when they are logged in they have the opportunity to post information much like what i'm doing now... this info goes into a list view in the page that appears after they logged in

Now i've tested it and it works, problem is I made lots of mistakes, now I want to edit it by making an edit page with the same controls as the post page but how do alter the info I posted?

code for posting info

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string answer = "NO";
    string strcon = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\VC_temps.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Store-Jobs", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("Job", TextBox1.Text);
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("JobType", DropDownList1.Text);
    SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("StartDate", TextBox3.Text);
    SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("Time", TextBox2.Text);
    SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("JobID", TextBox1.Text.Substring(3).ToUpper());
    SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("CompanyID", Session["CompID"]);
    SqlParameter p7 = new SqlParameter("PoistionFilled", answer);
    SqlParameter p8 = new SqlParameter("Description", TextBox4.Text);
    com.Parameters.Add(p1);
    com.Parameters.Add(p2);
    com.Parameters.Add(p3);
    com.Parameters.Add(p4);
    com.Parameters.Add(p5);
    com.Parameters.Add(p6);
    com.Parameters.Add(p7);
    com.Parameters.Add(p8);
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Labelinfo.Text = "Post successful.";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load in the textboxes the data by ID and then handle the update in SP of Store-Jobs. When the ID is greater then 0 do an update otherwise do an insert.

SQL Example;

```
If @ID > 0
'Update Store-Jobs
Else
'Insert Store Jobs
```

C#

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Store-Jobs", con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", Request.QueryString("ID") == Null ? Request.QueryString("ID") : 0);    
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Job", TextBox1.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobType", DropDownList1.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", TextBox3.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time", TextBox2.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobID", TextBox1.Text.Substring(3).ToUpper());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("CompanyID", Session["CompID"]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("PoistionFilled", answer);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", TextBox4.Text);
con.Open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
Labelinfo.Text = "Post successful.";
```

Comment: okay thanks that helps, but what forgot to ask is how do select the job that's going to be edited

Comment: When triggering the Button1_Click event you mean? Of on Page_Load?

Comment: like lets say thers more than one job posted, and I want to edit only one of these jobs how do I select the job I want to edit

Comment: You will need to implement a Datagrid, DataList or Repeater with the list of all items. Then on item click / edit click you fill the details in a new form